# How do I change the boot order for Ubuntu?

Tags: boot

Hello Ubuntu community!

I have two operating systems on my laptop (Windows 7 and Ubuntu), and I would like to change the boot order to Windows 7 first and if F2 or something is pressed on boot it will change to Ubuntu.

It is not in the BIOS because of Ubuntu being a partition.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the boot order in /etc/default/grub as root with nano or other text editor:

1. 'sudo nano /etc/default/grub'
2. Find the line GRUB_DEFAULT=0 and change to GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
3. Update grub 'sudo update-grub'
4. Check your grub menu while booting. Probably Windows is at number 3 or 4
5. Since, grub menu numbering starts with Zero, so, number 3 is number 2(0,1,2), similarly number 4 is actually number 3(0,1,2,3)
6. To set the default os on boot, issue 'sudo grub-set-default N' (N is the number corresponding the preferred OS)

That's it. Sorry for the ill formatted response, typing on phone.